# как отобразить html в WebBrowser WinForms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

Не получается реализовать отображение html файла в элементе WebBrowser, статьи MSDN читал, но не получается. Как реализовать код?

Comment: Окей, а что у вас есть на текущий момент? Дайте код.

Comment: не могу дать код как таковой, поскольку перебирал различные вариации в попытках отобразить html, потому и написал сюда в надежде на помощь с отображением содержимого в элементе браузер

Comment: Окей, начнём вот с чего: WinForms или WPF? И всё же C# или C++/CLI?

Comment: windows forms C++/CLI. как понимаю, это неподходящая комбинация?

Comment: Ну, C# было бы лучше. Но по идее не так страшно.

Comment: А сам WebControl (пустой) у вас получилось добавить?

Comment: да, WebBrowser добавил, но дальше у меня тупик, поскольку почти все  найденные методы на C# описаны, под C++ в основном методы запуска файла из директории ПК описаны

Comment: @ДмитрийКороль переведите заголовок на русский, пожалуста

Answer (score 1):

1. прочитать файл в строку - вызовом `File.ReadAllText(filename)`;
2. выставить содержимое `WebBrowser` равным этой строке - через свойство `DocumentText`:

   ```
   webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>"
   ```

Выставление `DocumentText` срабатывает только один раз. Если нужно несколько раз менять содержимое, используйте следующий код:

```
private void DisplayHtml(string html)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.Write(string.Empty);
    }
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
}
```

Comment: ну, мне, по сути, необходимо отобразить целиком html с форматированием текста, а не считать его построково только как текст. хотя, возможно, я вас неправильно понял, поскольку являюсь совсем новичком. получается, необходимо все прописывать тут? 'private: System::Void part4L1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    }'

Comment: `private: System::Void part4L1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) { непосредственно код }`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
String^ uriString = String::Format("file:///{0}", <тут путь к вашему html>);
webBrowser1->Navigate(gcnew Uri(uriString));
```

В случае, когда html лежит в том каталоге, где exe (а не где проект!), подойдёт что-то такое:

```
String^ dir = Path::GetDirectoryName(Application::ExecutablePath);
String^ path = Path::Combine(dir, "тут имя вашего html");
```

и дальше как обычно

```
String^ uriString = String::Format("file:///{0}", path);
webBrowser1->Navigate(gcnew Uri(uriString));
```